# Developing in Teams - What is the best Craft setup?

Tags: setup, workflow

We are currently working on a Craft project with 3 developers.

Our setup:
3 Local machines running Laravel Homestead and a local DB + Craft.
1 remote server holding Craft + db.

Our workflow:

- We are using Github for version control of our local files.
- For the DB we are currently using a dumb workaround we are very unhappy with :) . We are saving the DB in the craft-cp and git pushing the export to whatever branch we are working in. Then the next person has to import it locally whenever he makes changes to it.

We just thought using the same remote db on our server would be a better idea. Any better ideas? Is there something as good as Github but for DBs?
Or is there a better way to collaborate on a craft project anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The articles might be useful to you:

[Database & Asset Syncing Between Environments in Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/database-asset-syncing-between-environments-in-craft-cms)

[Multi-Environment Config for Craft CMS](https://nystudio107.com/blog/multi-environment-config-for-craft-cms)